# Is it possible to install .net 4.0 on Windows 2003 with IIS 6?

Tags: .net-4.0

Is it possible to install .net 4.0 on Windows 2003 with IIS 6?
Could anyone point me to a How-to guide?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course.  You download it from here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd582936.aspx where there are videos and documentation explaining how to install everything.